# Reactjs - Uncaught TypeError: $node.attr(...).tooltip is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap, summernote

I am working on SummerNote mention library and getting error -

```
Uncaught TypeError: $node.attr(...).tooltip is not a function
```

i am using `"react-summernote": "^2.0.0",`

react version - `"react": "^16.8.6",`

bootstrap -  `"bootstrap": "^4.4.1",`

react-bootstrap - `"react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",`

is there any help on this?

Comment: There was an issue opened in summernote repo a few minutes ago, I'm guessing that was you?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [issue comment](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/2157#issuecomment-298219811), `bootstrap` needs to be installed to prevent that error.
Another [comment](https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/2157#issuecomment-451622822) lower down says that Popper.js needs to be installed, as well.

```
npm i bootstrap @popperjs/core
```

I see that you already have `bootstrap` installed, so just installing `@popperjs/core` should fix it.

Comment: thanks for your answer :).
After installing     "@popperjs/core": "^2.3.3" same issue i am getting.
any other help?

Comment: @RaviBhandari no, sorry! It looks like a legitimate issue with SummerNote, hopefully someone there can fix it. All I had to suggest was installing `bootstrap` and `@popperjs/core`, and even those seem like they can/should be fixed in SummerNote.